# Access exclusive members of an object when it's passed into a method as an instance/type of it's superclass

Tags: scala, scalatest

I am new to scala. The following 4 classes relevant to my question are present in a test automation framework designed in Scala. Is it possible to access members(day, month, year) of an object (LoginPage) if it is being passed into a method as an instance of it's superclass (PageObject) and the superclass does not contain those members

```
trait PageObject {
  val rootUrl = "http://localhost:9999/basic-page"
  val back = "backLink"
  val submit = "submit"
  val url: String
  val heading: String
}


object LoginPage extends PageObject {
  val url =s"$rootUrl/login-page"
  val heading = "Heading heading"
  val day = "login_page_day"
  val month = "login_page__month"
  val year = "login_page__year"
}


import LoginPage
object Main {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val date = "15 August 2017"
    enterDateOnPage(date, LoginPage)
   }
 }

<current way>
class DateMethods {    
  def enterDateOnPage(date: String, page: PageObject) {
    val arr = date.split(" ")
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(arr(1)))
    numberField(LoginPage.day).value = arr(0)
    numberField(LoginPage.month).value = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString
    numberField(LoginPage.year).value = arr(2)
    click on name(LoginPage.submit)
  }
}

<preferred way>
class DateMethods {    
      def enterDateOnPage(date: String, page: PageObject) {
        val arr = date.split(" ")
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(arr(1)))
        numberField(page.day).value = arr(0)
        numberField(page.month).value = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString
        numberField(page.year).value = arr(2)
        click on name(page.submit)
      }
    }
```

Can the 'LoginPage.day' and the likes  be replaced by 'page.day' after confirming that the pageMatch is actually returning a LoginPage?

I did try something like this based on Samuel Heaney's answer, but it won't compile

```
def enterDateOnPage(date: String, page: PageObject) {
    val npage = getPage(page)

    val arr = date.split(" ")
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(arr(1)))

    numberField(npage.day).value = arr(0)
    numberField(npage.month).value = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString
    numberField(npage.year).value = arr(2)
    click on name(npage.submit)


  }

  def getPage(page:PageObject)={
    page match{
      case _:LoginPage.type => LoginPage
      case _:EntryFormPage.type => EntryFormPage
    }
```

Only works if i add day, month and year as members to PageObject trait, but that is not a feasible option for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull your date logic into its own trait and match on that.

```
trait Dates {
  val day: String
  val month: String
  val year: String
}

case object LoginPage extends PageObject with Dates {
  val day = ""
  val month = ""
  val year = ""
  // additional code
}
```

And now your function can match on the trait specifically

```
def enterDateOnPage(date: String, page: PageObject) {
  page match {
    case datePage: Dates => {
      // add log to validate date fields
    }
    case _ => // no-op
  }

  // additional code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use pattern matching to test if its a `LoginPage`.

```
class DateMethods {    
  def enterDateOnPage(date: String, page: PageObject): Unit = {
    page match {
      case LoginPage =>
        setUIFields(
          LoginPage.day,
          LoginPage.month,
          LoginPage.year,
          date
        )
      case LogoutPage =>
        setUIFields(...)
      case EntryFormPage =>
        setUIFields(...)
    }
    click on name(page.submit)
  }

  def setUIFields(
    day: String,
    month: String,
    year: String,
    date: String
  ): Unit = {
    val arr = date.split(" ")
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM").parse(arr(1)))
    numberField(day).value = arr(0)
    numberField(month).value = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1).toString
    numberField(year).value = arr(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for more of a solution which would work for multiple pages. If I have to repeat the code for every type of page I pass in, it beats the purpose of having a common method for all pages. For eg, I could cause LoginPage, LogoutPage, EntryFormPage which all extend PageObject, and I need the method to cater to all of them.

Comment: Can you just use a method you can call with different parameters if you do not want to repeat code? I updated the answer with an example.